# Spring JPA alternatives

Tags: java, spring

Does Spring have a SQL query engine without using JPA? I mean, so that you can write queries in a string and get an analog of ResultSet on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Spring JDBCTemplate. Examples[here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) or [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate)